# Non differentiable functions after first or second derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was asked to find a function that after getting the first or the second derivative it becomes non differentiable in all points. I've found some examples of non differentiable functions but not in all points nor after getting the first or the second derivative. For example, I found y = $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ but it is just non differentiable in (-1, 1). Thanks in advance for reading my inquiry,

Comment: Take a Weierstrass function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function and take its indefinite integral to get say a $C^1$ function whose derivative is differentiable nowhere.

Comment: By the way, $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$ is not at all an example of the kind you're looking for, since it's very much differentiable. It's only non-differentiable at the point $x=0$, for the trivial reason that it's undefined there. But if you let $f(0)=1$, the function becomes infinitely differentiable everywhere.